# How to make honeycomb borders? (CSS)

Tags: css, hover, border, border-radius

In general, the task is a little more difficult. Perhaps it is not `border-raudius` that should be used here. I do not know..

To better explain the problem, take a look at the following image:

[image]

**There is a list of items. On hover, element borders and horizontal lines on the sides change color.**

Even if I set the borders, I don’t know how to make horizontal lines on the sides and make them interact at the same time on hover.

Do you have any ideas how you can implement this? What approach is needed to solve this problem?

Using only CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: You could design and svg and use it inline. You could then change the stroke color of the svg using css. This is a complex UI, which I don't think is possible using just css.

Comment: Exactly. SVG. I didn't even think about him. Thanks for the advice!